# Can't use the id command to summon riot armor helmet

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

Ok so recently I got the scorched earth expansion pack for ark. I wanted to start the game off with some riot armor so I wouldn't be completely exposed to the elements. I got all the pieces I needed except for the helmet. I tried using the command but it would simply erase after I got done typing. If it helps any I'm playing this on the Xbox one. Is there another command to get it or will I have to learn the blueprints and actually craft it?

Comment: I've experienced this too. Riot helmets don't spawn with admin commands, not sure why.

Comment: Oh well. Guess I will just add experience and and spawn in the materials to make it